# Whould tags from different ”levels” be kept?

Tags: discussion

Should we keep tags from different “granularity levels”, even when one is clearly a child of another? In **[this example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6848664)**, [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) is added to a post already tagged [android-mediaplayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-mediaplayer).

Reduntant or helpful?

Comment: In general, having the most "broad" relevant tag will get more eyes on the post - there may well be people watching the `android` tag that aren't watching `android-mediaplayer` but could easily answer the question if they were to notice it. I think in general suggested edits shouldn't be used purely for re-tagging, but there wasn't really anything else to edit in that post (except maybe: "are reached" -> "is reached") and it adds value.